# How to test whether a method has been overriden in junit?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have this question, is there a test annotation or assertion which can tell if a method has been overriden in junit?

I'm currently implementing a test case which should tell whether the class `Foo`'s method `toString()` has overriden its super class.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do it like this probably:

```
 class.getMethod("toString").getDeclaringClass();
```

Here is a sample:

```
  class Test {
         public String toString(){
              return "From test";
         }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    String resut = Test.class.getMethod("toString").getDeclaringClass().getName();
    System.out.println(resut);
}
```

Now run this with toString firs overridden then comment it out and you will see the output and "Test" then "Object"